# openni kinect driver CPU usage

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm using the Kinect with a Turtlebot. I'm finding that the openni driver which I need to run is very CPU intensive. I've been looking for a way to decrease CPU usage by decreasing the amount of topics it publishes. From what I've read, it seams like the topics are only published if there is something subscribing to them. Is this correct? Is there anyway to cut down the driver to choose which video streams are available for use?

Thanks for any advice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30267/openni-kinect-driver-cpu-usage/) by [amck77](https://answers.ros.org/users/1864/amck77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-03-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, if you look at the code, the driver looks to see if something is subscribed and if so, then publishes the message.

You have access to the driver and can cut away what you want, but I don't think you will get much out of it.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2